# Delete c-style comments with possessive quantifier regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to understand how possessive quantifiers work. Is it possible to use this feature to remove for example comments from a string?
Here is what I tried:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = ' abc /* hi */ def /* h*i */';

say $str =~ s{/\*[^*]++\*/}{}sgr;
say $str =~ s{/\*.*+\*/}{}sgr;
say $str =~ s{/\*.*?\*/}{}sgr;
```

Output:

```
 abc  def /* h*i */
 abc /* hi */ def /* h*i */
 abc  def
```

Why does the possessive quantifiers not work here?

Comment: is `r` a modifier? Why you used that?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It performs non-destructive substitution and return the new value, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Po quantifier does his job well. what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ok, also the last line with non-greedy regex works.. The expected output would be comments removed.. But the question is more a general question about possessive quantifiers

Comment: @Avinash Raj, He's using `/r` because `say $str =~ s{/\*[^*]++\*/}{}sgr;` is simpler and cleaner than `(my $temp = $str) =~ s{/\*[^*]++\*/}{}sg; say $temp;`. `/r` was introduced in 5.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possessive quantifier does it's job well.

**Input string:**

```
my $str = ' abc /* hi */ def /* h*i */';
```

**Regex 1:**

```
/\*[^*]++\*/
```

`/\*` - Matches the first `/*` and the last `/*`.

`[^*]++` - Not of `*` one or more times. `++` won't allow backtracking. So this matches first `/* hi` and the following pattern `\*/` matches the `*/` which exists next to the `hi` . And at the same time, regex engine tries to do the same job in the next `/*`. That is, `/\*` matches the `/*` which exists just before to the `h*i`. Come up with the next pattern `[^*]++` matches upto the `/* h`, then it stops matching once it finds the `*`. Then it  won't go further ie, (*forward or backwards*) because of the possessive `++` quantifier which won't allow backtracking. So that  the second part got failed.

Finally we have a match of `/* hi */`. Replacing those characters with an empty string will give you the output of `abc  def /* h*i */`

**Regex 2:**

```
/\*.*+\*/
```

`/\*` - Matches the `/*` which exists just before to the `hi` and `h*i`

`.*` - Matches all the characters greedily upto the last.

`.*+` - Because of the `+` which exists just after to `*` won't allow backtracking, the regex marker is at the end of the line and fail to match `*/` because there isn't a `*/` exists after  the end of the line. So this regex got failed and it won't match even a single character from the input string.

Finally  `s{/\*.*+\*/}{}sgr` returns the input string as output.(*Note that the curly braces in the above pattern are regex delimiters*)

**Solution:**

To remove the comment part, i suggest you to use the below regex,

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dD1zE2/4)

OR

```
/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dD1zE2/6)

Comment: Thanks, but why does, for example `/\*.*+\*/` not work? And can possessive quantifiers be used to remove comments? If so, is it more efficient than non-greedy regex?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this with a possessive quantifier is to use this kind of pattern that allows any `*` inside the comment:

```
$str =~ s{/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!/))*+\*/}{}g
```

The idea is to separate two possible cases in an alternation:

1. all characters that are not a `*`
2. one or more `*` not followed by a `/`

Finally, you only need to make possessive the quantifier of the non-capturing group that contains the alternation.

But an alternation and a lookahead have a cost. So, an other possible way consists to use, instead of an alternation, this pattern with an atomic group with a lazy quantifier:

```
/\*(?>[^*]*\*+)+?/
```

Note that it uses the `+` quantifier to ensure the presence of the final `*`.
So the impact on performances due to the lazy quantifier is very limited (only when a group of `*` is met).

Even this second way uses a lazy quantifier, it is probably a faster way and needs few steps to match a whole comment.

**Note:** in most languages, a C comment that is not closed with `*/` runs until the end of a file. Let's see the versions of the two patterns to handle this case:

first pattern: [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB7vJ7/1) *(*)*

```
/\*(?:[^*]+|\*+(?!/))*+(?:\*/|\z)
```

second pattern: [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX9uZ5/1) *(*)*

```
/\*(?>[^*]*(?:\*+|\z(*ACCEPT)))+?/
```

*(*) click the debug item to see the number of steps needed for each ways.*